# Jquery email validation in registration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I need to validate the user email address before submission. I found this regex online, but i don't know how to use it so it will work with my jquery.
Can someone compile this code for me? I don't know how to do that.

Here is my code

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mail = $('input[name=email]');

    $('input[type="email"]').keyup( function() {
        if(mail.val() !=) {
            $('#validate').html("Invalid email");
        } else {
            $('#validate').html("Valid");
        }
        // ...
    });
});
```

**REGEX PATTERN**

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = /^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.)+([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.?$/i;
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
```

I don't know how to make this to work for me?
Or if you have any other easier way to archive this please do it for me.

Comment: Easiest way `<input type="email" />`

Comment: But what if the users enter something like this `myemai@ok..com` it will work that why i need to use this @Tushar

Comment: Email validation are a though subject, there are a lots of regexp out there. You should do a basic check, and/or use `<input type="email"/>` as stated in the previous comment. On a side note, you should not trust client side validations as they can easily be bypassed.

Comment: I dont think `..` can be together in email. You can refer [Wiki - Post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to validate email address. Hopefully it will help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mail = $('input[name=email]');
    var value = mail.val();
    $('input[type="email"]').keyup( function() {
        if(!validateEmail(value)) {
            $('#validate').html("Invalid email");
        } else {
            $('#validate').html("Valid");
        }
        // ...
    });
});
```

and the regex

```
function validateEmail(value) {
    var emailtest = /^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i;
    return emailtest.test(value);
}
```

Comment: How about TLDs like `museum` or `enterprises`, see: http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db  and it doesn't match `me@localhost`